# Seasonal decompose of monthly data including NA in r

Tags: r, time-series, na

I need help to decompose my monthly data which have seasonality, but it does not work because NA values are not removed. There may be another problem. Please look at my data and errors as below.

```
    ts.monthly<-ts(monthly$rBC.median, frequency=12, start=c(2006, 4))
    ts.monthly
        Jan        Feb        Mar        Apr        May        Jun
    2006                                   5.1656479  6.2847959 19.4833690
    2007  1.4252665  2.9127775  2.8912652  7.5326158  8.6182227 23.2129310
    2008         NA  1.8200842  1.3488755  2.0700927  5.3541366  8.6916708
    2009  1.2531161  1.5075780  2.4955524 10.6724704 10.1367162 16.0362127
    2010  0.8850190  2.4974866  1.8459976  9.2297697  3.8203789  7.1492986
    2011  2.6990434  0.4570701  1.3787403  5.8739804  4.1669501 13.2228535
    2012         NA  2.0670538  1.3758499 11.7306663  4.1248775 12.3604423
                Jul        Aug        Sep        Oct        Nov        Dec
    2006  9.8028986  7.8167810  2.1333807  2.5777504  1.9022561  2.7254065
    2007  4.2121577  8.8604768 12.0017155  4.0978332  1.6053110         NA
    2008  5.7338211  9.7432563  4.6548508  1.3589789  0.9650082  1.2788504
    2009 11.7632775 11.2299683  1.6229679  1.0333217  1.0481580  1.0734208
    2010  3.5996501  4.3245873  4.4586863  1.6403104  2.8622518  1.2564256
    2011  3.0463918  7.1515472  6.5613683  1.3715623  1.9757217  5.4901524
    2012 11.1010563  3.6220968  2.2597341  

   ts.monthly=na.omit(ts.monthly)  
    Error in na.omit.ts(ts.monthly) : time series contains internal NAs
   ts.monthly.com<-decompose(ts.monthly)
    Error in na.omit.ts(x) : time series contains internal NAs
   ts.monthly$seasonal
    Error in ts.monthly$seasonal : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I do not understand why na.omit does not work. How can I treat this NA??

Finally, after using a function "decompose", I want to take only "trend" without seasonality, and then apply sen's slope estimator to get a slope for linear trend. Will it work?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try filling in the missing values using a seasonal Kalman filter by employing `na.StructTS` from the zoo package first:

```
library(zoo)
decompose(na.StructTS(ts.monthly))
```

zoo has many other `na.` functions as well: `na.aggregate`, `na.approx`, `na.fill`, `na.locf`, `na.spline`, `na.StructTS`, `na.trim`.

Comment: Now, I want to use the data which seasonality is removed to get a slop of the linear trend. I think sen's slope (nonparametric) is a good choice. But I am not sure if i can use directly "ts.monthly$trend" to get the slope. I mean i don't know what values in "ts.monthly$trend" means. It has the same unit of my initial data (ts.monthly$x)?? Do you have any good idea to get a slope for robust linear trend?

Answer (score 6):

The X-13ARIMA-SEATS software, accessible by the R-package [seasonal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seasonal), handles missing values and seasonal decomposition in a single step:

```
library(seasonal)

# a monthly time series with some missing values
AirPassengersNA <- AirPassengers
AirPassengersNA[c(2, 24)] <- NA

m <- seas(AirPassengersNA, na.action = na.x13)
head(m$data)

        final  seasonal seasonaladj    trend irregular adjustfac
[1,] 122.5860 0.9029705    122.5860 122.6289 0.9996500 0.9136445
[2,] 123.8615 0.9492046    123.8615 123.8656 0.9999671 0.9408045
[3,] 125.0191 1.0701984    125.0191 125.3132 0.9976535 1.0558387
[4,] 127.4633 1.0028864    127.4633 126.6222 1.0066428 1.0120561
[5,] 127.2526 0.9494692    127.2526 126.8592 1.0031006 0.9508650
[6,] 126.0700 1.0771444    126.0700 126.1723 0.9991886 1.0708339
```

Answer (score 4):

The [imputeTS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/index.html) package is a R package solely dedicated to replacing missing values in time series. You can use a function of the package before performing your decomposition.

The `na_seadec()` and the `na_kalman()` are especially good for replacing missing data in seasonal time series. But there are also other advanced methods available (Link to [imputeTS Paper](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-009/index.html)).

You would use it like this for this problem:

```
library(imputeTS)
x <- decompose(na_seadec(yourTimeSeries))
```

or if you want to use the na_kalman method instead:

```
library(imputeTS)
x <- decompose(na_kalman(yourTimeSeries))
```

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this for a long time too.

Just use `na.locf` from the `zoo` package on your `ts` object. `na.locf` returns a `ts` object, so there are no worries about a changed object type.

Use:

```
    library(zoo)
    season_ts <- na.locf(season_ts)
```

where `season_ts` is your `ts` object.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is looking for a Bayesian alternative, one choice is the `Rbeast` package; it does time series decomposition and changepoint detection at the same time, with missing values allowed and gap-filled automatically. Possible outputs include individual components (e.g., season, trend, and outliers), changepoints detected separately for the seasonal and trend components, changepoint occurrence probabilities over time, time-varying slope and time-varying probabilities of slopes being positive or negative, and time-varying seasonal amplitude.

Here is a quick example

```
library(Rbeast) 
co2[ sample(1:length(co2), 200) ] <- NA  # Throw NAs into 200 random locations
plot(beast(co2))
```