# Why does using decompose function in R remove some of my data (Time Series)?

Tags: r, time-series

So I used the decompose function in R to decompose my time series so I can turn my time series into stationary time series and then do an ARMA model. However, The result as below shows up:

[image]

when I looked at the value on R Studio, It shows that the value is NA. Is there a problem with my time series or should I use other method to decompose my Time Series?

Comment: could you please include a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this way people can figure out a precise answer... I would try to handle the NAs before processing (possibly one can fill all up 0, also there are many interpolation/filling methods available in R): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694558/seasonal-decompose-of-monthly-data-including-na-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean NA's in `$random` and `$trend`, since trend is obtained by moving average, it's normal to print `NA` at front and end
It seems you let frequency as 12, then first six and final six value will be `NA`